# onclick for a button

Tags: jquery

I have a code at a button

```
onClick="$('img').removeClass('highlighted');$(this).addClass('highlighted')
```

well it will make the button gets highlighted but is it possible to add a check statement in there to see if the button is already highlighted and dehighlight it rather then letting it just stay highlighted?

Comment: thanks for all the prompt replies, all the solutions worked but i probably choose the one that is close to what i have, the one liner rather than adding a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the jQuery method: [`hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

```
onClick="if($('img').hasClass('highlighted')) {$('img').removeClass('highlighted');} else {$(this).addClass('highlighted')}
```

Comment: Note that you're saying "if img doesn't have class highlighted, then remove class highlighted" which doesn't make sense. Probably just a typo though.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`.click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) in javascript instead, as it's easier to read and manage afterwards:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#button").click(function() {
            if ($(this).hasClass('highlighted')) {
                $('img').addClass('highlighted');
                $(this).removeClass('highlighted');
            } else {
                $('img').removeClass('highlighted');
                $(this).addClass('highlighted');
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

You can also use [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#button").click(function() {
            $('img').toggleClass('highlighted');
            $(this).toggleClass('highlighted');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: the part where by 
     if ($($this).hasClass('highlighted')) {
                $('img').removeClass('highlighted');
                $(this).addClass('highlighted');
            }
why is there a need to $(this).addClass('highlighted'); when i wanted to remove it?

Comment: That was a typo from my side, and it's fixed now for future use. Glad you found your answer.

Answer (score 1):

That code looks crazy. Are you using jQuery? If so, do the check within the click handler itself.

```
$("img").on("click", function(event){

   var $this = $(this);

   if($this.hasClass("highlighted")) {
      $this.removeClass("highlighted")
   } else {
      $this.addClass("highlighted")
   }

});
```

Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

Very simple boss: Use hasClass()

```
$('img').click(function(){

if($(this).hasClass('highlighted')){
  $('img').removeClass('highlighted');
}
else{
 $(this).addClass('highlighted')
}


});
```